# why is glVertexAttribDivisor crashing?

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl, vertex, instancing

I am trying to render some trees with instancing. This is rather weird, but before sleeping yesterday night, I checked the code, and it was in a running state, when I got up this morning, it is crashing when I am calling `glVertexAttribDivisor` I haven't changed any code since yesterday.

Here is how I am sending data to GPU for instancing.

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &iVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (ml_instance->i_positions.size()*sizeof(glm::vec4)) , NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, (ml_instance->i_positions.size()*sizeof(glm::vec4)), &ml_instance->i_positions[0]);
```

And then in vertex specification--

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i_positions, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i_positions);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(i_positions,1); // **THIS IS WHERE THE PROGRAM CRASHES**

    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0,TREES_INSTANCE_COUNT);
```

I have checked `ml_instance->i_positions`, it has all the data that needs to render.

I have checked the value of `i_positions` in vertex shader, it is the same as whatever I have defined there.

I am little out of ideas here, everything looks pretty much fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the program in debug mode, and found out that `glVertexAttribPointer` was NULL. 
After restarting my windows the program started running like it was before.

I am using glew along with win32 in VS2008, but one thing i do not understand is, why glVertexAttirbPOinter was NULL? I was initializing glew properly. and it was getting initialized everytime i started the program. Why i wasn't gettinga valid address for that method?

Comment: It could be that your graphics driver crashed during some earlier programming (or other shenanigans) and that Windows was unable to recover it fully.

Comment: hmm, could be. I did not get error, or anything, but i was playing a graphics hungry game before starting with OpenGL.

Comment: Laptop with switchable graphics?

Comment: Yes Darth, it was a laptop with switchable graphics.